# Finding Probability of Next Character In String Given Previous Characters?

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, generator, probability

I am trying to discover a way to find (and store) the probability of a character following another character in a sequence of characters in Java.

Given a data set of [character sequences](http://deron.meranda.us/data/census-derived-all-first.txt/):

If a word starts with 'A' what is the probability of all the possible characters next in the sequence of the string of the data set (e.g. 'b', 'c', 'd')? And from this probability, what is the probability of next characters in the sequence?

Names:

- ADDA
- ANNA
- ADAM

2nd character after 'a' as 1st: 66.6% 'd', 33.3% 'n'

3rd character after 'd' as 2nd: 50% 'd', 50% 'a'

3rd character after 'n' as 2nd: 100% 'n'

4th character after 'd' as 3rd: 100% 'a'

4th character after 'n' as 3rd: 100% 'a'

4th character after 'a' as 3rd: 100% 'm'

Is there a way to store all such data in a usable format such that I can use the data to generate characters after a given first character based on the probability of the following characters in the data set?

I want to generate a list of names in this way:

1. Randomly choose first character
2. Append character chosen from list of possible characters and their probabilities
3. Rinse and repeat with varying character lengths

I'm not asking for a full solution -- just a suggestion of how this could be done.

I apologize if this question has been asked. And please let me know how to improve my question if you find any issues with it.

Comment: Please see [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: I think in the context of text processing (either by words or by letters) that Markov chains are associated with so-called "n-grams". So that's another keyword to look for.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that happens to find this question: I found [this blog post](https://itssmee.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/java-example-of-markov-chain/) that has a nice tutorial on Markov Chains which are used to predict next character probability among many things. Here is [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) for Markov Chains.